# Как создать class?

Tags: php

```
$get = file_get_contents("http://sdfdsfsdfdsfsd");
$decode = json_decode($get, TRUE); // TRUE for in array format
foreach($decode['SearchResponse']['Web']['Results'] as $res)
{
echo('<div id="res">');
echo "<p><div id='desc'>".$res['Description']." - <a href='".$res['Url']."' rel='nofollow'  target='_blank'>read more</a></div></p>"; // display everything
echo('</div>');
}
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сделать тут class, к примеру

***class MyClass**, чтобы скрипт работал через этот класс*

Comment: Книги тут нужно начинать читать. Потому как это тупик, судя по вашим вопросам вы шли давно к нему.
А класс создать просто:

    class MyClass {} // готово

Comment: Ну так не понял я, вот и попросил помощи. Чтобы работа скрипта шла через class.
____

Кто-нибудь подскажет?

Comment: @jikol, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Официальная документация PHP доступна на русском языке [**вот здесь**](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php)

Создаём класс:

```
class MyClass {

    public function MyMethod () {

        $get = file_get_contents("http://sdfdsfsdfdsfsd");
        $decode = json_decode($get, TRUE); // TRUE for in array format

        foreach($decode['SearchResponse']['Web']['Results'] as $res)
        {
            echo('<div id="res">');
            echo "<p><div id='desc'>".$res['Description']." - <a href='".$res['Url']."' rel='nofollow'  target='_blank'>read more</a></div></p>";
            echo('</div>');
        }

    }
}
```

Используем класс:

```
$object = new MyClass();
$object->MyMethod();
```